# I don't understand Terminal Points.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've just started to learn about finding terminal points of a unit circle.  One thing that I really don't understand is how I would do find the terminal point with a negative angle and with the numbers including square roots.  One of my example problems that I can't understand is to choose the point on the terminal side of $-210^\circ$.  Wouldn't both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates need to be negative? My options are $(-1,1)$, $(\sqrt{3},-1)$, $(-\sqrt{3},1)$, and $(-1, \sqrt{3})$.

Comment: Do the following: `$\sqrt{n}$` for $\sqrt{n}$. I'll fix the formatting up for you, but take a look at the edits to see how it's done in the future.

Answer (score 4):

"terminal point" isn't standard terminology as far as I know, so I'm just going to take a guess as to what you mean. Let me know if I guessed wrong.

There's not much difference between positive and negative angles. Positive angles just mean you move counter-clockwise from $(1,0)$, and negative angles mean you move clockwise. So the terminal point of $-210^\circ$ should be:

[image]

Comment: Nice picture! (+1)

Comment: MS Paint makes a okay illustrator out of anyone. :)

Comment: That's $-210^\circ$, right?

Comment: @EricStucky Edited. Thanks for the catch!